# Cannot get feature coordinates so I can get its closest feature

Tags: openlayers-3

I have a vector layer in Openlayers 3.9.0. Geoserver gets data from PostGIS and I grab the layer with `ol.source.Vector`.

The GeoJSON format of the returning data is

```
    {"type":"FeatureCollection","totalFeatures":422,"features":
[{"type":"Feature","id":"myLayer.709","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":
[2391735.8907621,4695330.8039257005]},"geometry_name":"myLayer_geom","properties"
:{"myLayer_name":"Hello"....next feature
```

So I get the first feature by its ID and try to find its closest feature according to its coordinates. This is my code

```
var bb = (sourceVector.getFeatureById('myLayer.709')).getCoordinates()
var aa = getClosestFeatureToCoordinate(bb);
console.log(aa);
```

I get `Cannot read property 'getCoordinates' of null` error.

Why is that? What am I missing?

Also, the API for [`getFeatureById`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.source.Cluster.html#getFeatureById) implies that the id must be a number, but in my case is a string (`myLayer.709`). On the other hand,  a [feature](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.Feature.html) can get a string as an ID and an ID can be set during data reading.

EDIT

This is the whole code (layer switcher module [here](https://github.com/walkermatt/ol3-layerswitcher))

```
var textent = ol.proj.transformExtent([2297128.5, 4618333, 2459120.25, 4763120], 'EPSG:900913', 'EPSG:3857');

    var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM({})});

    var bingMapsAerial = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.BingMaps({
            key: 'aaaa',
            imagerySet:'AerialWithLabels'
        })
    });       

    var ait = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/mymap/wms?',
       params: {'LAYERS': 'mymap:polygons, mymap:lines', 'TILED': true,  'VERSION': '1.3.0','FORMAT': 'image/png' ,'CRS': 'EPSG:900913'},
       serverType: 'geoserver'
     })
   })

var sourceVector = new ol.source.Vector({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    useSpatialIndex : true,
    loader: function (extent) {
        $.ajax('http://localhost:5550/geoserver/mymap/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=mymap:mylayer&outputFormat=application/json&BBOX='+extent.join(','), 
        {type: 'GET'})
        .done(      
         function(response) {
                    var geojsonFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON({});
                    sourceVector.addFeatures(geojsonFormat.readFeatures(response,{dataProjection : projection,featureProjection : projection}));
                })
        .fail(function () {alert("no");});
    },

    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
});


var fill = new ol.style.Fill({
color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)'
});

var stroke = new ol.style.Stroke({
color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)'
});

var circle = new ol.style.Circle({
radius: 6,
fill: fill,
stroke: stroke
});

layerVector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: sourceVector,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        fill: fill,
        stroke: stroke,
        image: circle
      })
});

    layer.set('title','a');
    layer.set('type','base');
    bingMapsAerial.set('title','b');
    bingMapsAerial.set('type','base');
    ait.set('title','ait');
    ait.set('type','base');

    var kbz = new ol.interaction.KeyboardZoom();
    var dr = new ol.interaction.DragRotateAndZoom();
    var control = new ol.control.FullScreen();
    var ext = new ol.control.ZoomToExtent({extent: textent});   
    var center = ol.proj.transform([21.54967, 38.70250], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');

    var view = new ol.View({
        center: center,
        zoom: 6,
        extent : textent,
        maxZoom:20
    });

    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers:[bingMapsAerial, layer, ait, layerVector],
        view: view
    });

    map.getView().fit(textent, map.getSize()); 
    map.addInteraction(kbz);
    map.addInteraction(dr);
    map.addControl(control);
    map.addControl(ext);
    var layerSwitcher = new ol.control.LayerSwitcher();
    map.addControl(layerSwitcher);

        var bb = sourceVector.getFeatureById('mylayer.709').getGeometry().getCoordinates();
    var aa = sourceVector.getClosestFeatureToCoordinate(bb);
    console.log(aa);
```

**UPDATE**

In the console, if I hit `map.getLayers()` I get the vector layer and a `idIndex_` array that includes all the features (709 too). But in my code if I do `var cc = sourceVector.getFeatures(); console.log(cc);` I get `[ ]` , just two empty brackets. Does this means that the features are not done loading before I try to get one by ID?

**UPDATE 2**
If I remove the

```
var bb=sourceVector.getFeatureById('mylayer.709').getGeometry().getCoordinates();
var aa = sourceVector.getClosestFeatureToCoordinate(bb);
console.log(aa);
```

and put it in the response function that reads features, after the wfs request, it works

```
.done(      
function(response) {
var geojsonFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON({});
sourceVector.addFeatures(geojsonFormat.readFeatures(response,{dataProjection :projection,featureProjection : projection}));

    //-------------add the following

    var bb=sourceVector.getFeatureById('mylayer.709').getGeometry().getCoordinates();
    var aa = sourceVector.getClosestFeatureToCoordinate(bb);
    console.log(aa); 
                        })
```

Does this means that this is my only option? Why cant I set my vector layer, get the features, set my map and access features? In a real scenario, after all loading its done, a user picks a random feature and gets the closer. Is impossible to know the id. Playing with features while reading them is not practical and doesnot makes sense. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
var bb = (sourceVector.getFeatureById('myLayer.709'))
    .getGeometry().getCoordinates();
var aa = sourceVector.getClosestFeatureToCoordinate(bb);
console.log(aa);
```

`ol.Feature#id` is always (https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/v3.9.0/src/ol/source/vectorsource.js#L694) treated as string.

**UPDATE** - http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/fn721xdk/

Tell OL3 your [data projection](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.0/apidoc/ol.format.GeoJSON.html#readFeature) when reading your json features:

```
var features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(geojsonObject, {
    dataProjection: 'EPSG:3857',
    featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
});
```

Comment: A helpful observation. But now I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getGeometry' of null` error. Seems that I cannot get the feature correctly, but I know its there, I see it on the map and I get no errors on my `wfs` request. I cannot see the problem. Any tips? Thanks

Comment: In my loader I have `.done(  
   function(response) {
                    var geojsonFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON({});
                    sourceVector.addFeatures(geojsonFormat.readFeatures(response,{dataProjection : projection,featureProjection : projection}));
                })` and `var projection = ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857');`. By the way I see all the layers in the console, they are loaded properly.

Comment: If I remove the quotes and do like `var bb = sourceVector.getFeatureById(myLayer.709).getGeometry().getCoordinates();` I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` reffering to that line.  And no layers rendered on the map. Sorry for asking you again, but I cannot see the error. Thanks

Comment: OK, I wont remove the quotes, but I still get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getGeometry' of null`. Still searching for a solution.

Comment: Create a fiddle!! Or fork mine.

Comment: I think a fiddle is pointless, because I would have to use external sources and make large modifications to my original code for the fiddle to work, so maybe the error will slip away. Maybe it will work for the fiddle, but not in my code. I updated my OP including my full code. Thanks again

Comment: In the console, if I hit `map.getLayers()` I get the vector layer and a `idIndex_` array that includes all the features (709 too). But in my code if I do ` var cc = sourceVector.getFeatures();
 console.log(cc);` I get `[ ]` , just two empty brackets.

Comment: It's pretty obvious that you must ***wait*** your response from AJAX, then, and only then, you can get your features.

Comment: I now understand OL a little better because of your efforts. Check my answer. I cannot thank you enough.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Jonatas Walker is right, I have to wait for the Ajax to finish loading all the features on the vector layer and then I can play with features.

So, to know when Ajax finished I kept the same code as in my OP, but I added.

```
       function(response) {
                    var geojsonFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON({});
                    sourceVector.addFeatures(geojsonFormat.readFeatures(response,{dataProjection : projection,featureProjection : projection}));
                    ww();//<---added this to the existing response function
                })
```

So, when its all finished, all features are loaded, now can access them. I call a function

So, after adding to the map controls and interactions, I replaced this

```
var bb = sourceVector.getFeatureById('mylayer.709').getGeometry().getCoordinates();
    var aa = sourceVector.getClosestFeatureToCoordinate(bb);
    console.log(aa);
```

with this

```
 function ww(){
    var rr = sourceVector.getFeatureById('mylayer.709').getGeometry().getCoordinates();
    var hh = sourceVector.getClosestFeatureToCoordinate(rr);
    console.log("The name of the closest feature is : "+hh.get("mylayer_name"));
    }
```

But, `mylayer.709` is a point. So in case a map has also lines and polygons and users can click any feature and you are not looking for a fixed feature (you dont know the id beforehand)

Just add this after the ww function

```
 var select = new ol.interaction.Select();//simple click interaction
 map.addInteraction(select);//add it to the map

 select.on('select', function(e) {//on every select (=click)

   //get the extent of the first selected feature (from the e.selected array)
    var aa = e.selected[0].getGeometry().getExtent();

   //in case of line or polygon get the center of that extent (=just a point)
    var oo = ol.extent.getCenter(aa);

   //use that center (=point) to get the name of the closest feature
   console.log((sourceVector.getClosestFeatureToCoordinate(oo)).get("mylayer_name")) ;
 });
```

***EDIT***

I apologise. Turns out there is a bug. In this case

[image]

if I click the polygons I get the names of the name of the closest feature, but if I click the points, I get the name of that point, so if I click the "testpoint9" I get "testpoint9"  but I should be getting "8" or "u" or "e" or something else. So I guess has to do with points.

I changed the content of the function to

```
    var closestType = e.selected[0].getGeometry().getType();
    var oo;
    if (closestType === 'Point'){
        oo = e.selected[0].getGeometry().getCoordinates();
    }
    else{
        var aa = e.selected[0].getGeometry().getExtent();
        oo = ol.extent.getCenter(aa);
    }

    console.log("---------------------------------------------------");
    console.log("Name of closest : "+sourceVector.getClosestFeatureToCoordinate(oo).get('mylayer_name'));
```

but still the same bug. Any tips? Thanks

Comment: Glad to see your success.

Comment: @JonatasWalker Hey, I just found a bug, thought you should check it out too.